# time data does not match format when it can

Tags: python-2.7

I got an error that is particularly strange. The code I'll give you run, but from time to time, our server (using apache2) hit this error:

```
ValueError: time data '7:00 PM' does not match format '%I:%M %p'
```

Strangely, this code works, the ValueError sometimes says otherwise...:

```
print datetime.strptime('7:00 PM', '%I:%M %p')
```

To fix the issue, from time to time, we simply reload our Apache2 server and up, it goes away! I can't figure out what's going on. I'm thinking that maybe there is an encoding issue with the text and the log is hiding it from us, but I'm programmatically unable to force this error :)

Any ideas?